# RaveReport - Print Non Database Information

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, rave-reports

Im using Rave report tool to making reports for my applications written by Delphi 7. 
I want to send a parameter from an edit box to my report. some runtime given information that has no any relation to my database. How can i send them to rave report for printing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the below process to pass parameter:

1. Choose File/New Report.
2. Define the parameter that you want to print.
3. To do that open the property editor of the parameters property.
4. List all parameters of this report, each on a separate line.
5. Parameters can be printed using a DataText component, available in the Report tab of the component pallete.
6. Open the property editor of the DataField property.
7. Under project parameters, select the parameter which you need to display in the data text and click **Add Parameter** button.
8. You can view `Param.<parameter name>` in the Data Text of the property editor.
9. Write the following code in Delphi Project

   procedure TFormMain.btnExecuteClick(Sender: TObject);
   begin
     RvProject.Open;
     RvProject.SelectReport(Report Name,False);
     RvProject.SetParam(parameter name,'your text');
     RvProject.Execute;
     RvProject.Close;
   end;